# How to prevent duplication when implementing datamappers for different database engines?

Tags: php, sql, oop, datamapper, data-mapping

In my project I want to build in support for multiple database engines. I am achieving this through datamappers which are placed in the model layer. A simple example of this would look like (sorry for the wall of code, skip to the end if you want to get the gist):

**User**

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Application\Model\Mapper;

class User
{
    private $mapper;

    private $id;

    public function __construct(Mapper $mapper, $id)
    {
        $this->mapper = $mapper;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->mapper->updatePassword($this->id, $password);
    }
}
```

**Mapper interface**

```
namespace Application\Model;

interface UserMapper
{
    public function updatePassword($id, $password);
}
```

**MySQL mapper**

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Application\Model\Mapper;

class UserMysqlMapper implements Mapper
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(\PDO $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function updatePassword($id, $password)
    {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare('UPDATE user SET password = :password WHERE userid = :userid');
        $stmt->execute(['password' => $password, 'userid' => $id]);
    }
}
```

**PostgreSQL mapper**

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Application\Model\Mapper;

class UserPgsqlMapper implements Mapper
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(\PDO $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function updatePassword($id, $password)
    {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare('UPDATE user SET password = :password WHERE userid = :userid');
        $stmt->execute(['password' => $password, 'userid' => $id]);
    }
}
```

**Loading the stuff**

```
$connection = new \PDO(dsn stuff);
$mapper = \Application\Model\UserPgsqlMapper($connection);
$user = \Application\Model\User($mapper, 1);
$user->setPassword('new password');
```

As you can see I have two mappers basically with duplicated code (the queries are the same for both engines). This somewhat "rapes" the DRY principle, however I just don't see a good / clean / correct way to prevent this. Note that of course this is just a simple example and normally there would be queries which would not be the same across different database engines.

I have thought about letting the mappers extend some mapper with the base queries, however this feels even more dirty, because there simply can not be a base query for something.

I have also asked this in PHP chat yesterday and the conclusion was basically "fak the duplication and go on with your life" and the more I think about it the more I think that's the only real option I have.

But to be sure I am not missing some clean and smart solution I thought I would post a question here.

Answer (score 1):

If the example code is representative, the duplication is a real code smell. You're not only duplicating the queries, but the PHP code is also identical; you're writing a lot of duplicate code here, and it isn't earning its keep.

I would consider treating the queries as a resource, not as code.

For instance, create a file called "queries.php", and set each query as a variable:

```
$update_password= ["default" => "UPDATE user SET password = :password WHERE userid = :userid"]
$create_user = ["default" => "insert into blabla"
                "mysql"   => "insert into wibble"]
```

When executing the query, check if there's a database-specific version, otherwise use the default.

You might also consider whether the mapper classes are really earning their keep - if all they are doing is executing slightly different SQL statements, you might be able to get rid of them, or at least pull up a lot of code into a super class.

For instance, instead of an interface, you might create a datamapper class, with the default behaviour, and pull in the query appropriate to the current database. If a specific database really does require a different implementation of a method, you can override that method in the database-specific subclass.

Something like:

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Application\Model\Mapper;

class UserDefaultMapper
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(\PDO $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function updatePassword($id, $password)
    {
        $query = getQueryForDB("updatePassword", $connection);

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare(query);
        $stmt->execute(['password' => $password, 'userid' => $id]);
    }
    public function createUser($name){
    ...
    }
}
```

If "createUser()" requires a database-specific implementation (e.g. to retrieve the userID), you would create an override:

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Application\Model\Mapper;

class UserMySQLMapper extends UserDefaultMapper
{
    public function createUser($name){
    ...
    }
}
```

This gives you less code, less duplicated code (connection management, statement execution etc.), allows the most common variation (different queries for different engines) to be managed through a resource file rather than inheritance, but still gives you the power to override when you need to.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by code duplication, because there really isn't much code going on in there. Could you elaborate? Also the mapper classes are there to separate the persistence layer from the other layers. Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: As far as I can tell, every line of the two database mappers is duplicated - this is likely to get out of hand quite quickly. What if you decide to change the way you set up connections - you would need to modify every mapper file everywhere. I've updated the answer to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> I have thought about letting the mappers extend some mapper with the
>   base queries, however this feels even more dirty, because there simply
>   can not be a base query for something.

As of PHP 5.4.0, PHP implements a method of code reuse called [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies.

Also, the [Flourish](http://flourishlib.com/) PHP Unframework is able to run on different databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, MSSQL, Oracle, DB2). It includes support for [one dialect of SQL](http://flourishlib.com/docs/FlourishSql) across all database types. You can use it directly in your project, or draw its idea of a universal SQL dialect.

Finally, you can even combine these two approaches (traits and SQL dialect). For simple queries, use a subset of SQL, while for advanced queries, "mixin" the query from different traits.

btw, I've been using Flourish for many non-trivial projects on databases such as MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, and MS SQL Server. I recommend use it directly.

---

**UPDATE:** You may also refer to the [database abstraction layer](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aDatabase_access#Wrapper_functions) in MediaWiki. It builds up SQL queries for different backends, but keeps the same interface for application use.

Comment: I'm going to look into Flourish thanks. I don't like `Traits` though, because it is just another way of introducing tight coupling imho.

Comment: @PeeHaa I haven't tried Traits either, in real-world project. :-) Then try flourish.

Comment: Just looked into Flourish and I'm not really liking what I am seeing (sorry). `static`s all over the place and full of bad practice :(

Comment: @PeeHaa That's all right. Then you can roll your own based on its SQL dialect style :-D